# How do I reduce my code using a function when using a lot of references like PIXELS_PER_INCH = 72?

Tags: java

I have some code that needs reducing and it was recommended to me on Reddit.com that I use functions to do it. But the problem is the code is mostly a collection of `public static final` "references" such as `PIXELS_PER_INCH = 72`.

I open sourced my [app](https://github.com/jacksmartie/PhotoMem) on GitHub, if anyone wants to look at it that way.

Here's an example of where I assign values to my constants:

```
public static final int PICTURES_4 = 0;
public static final int PICTURES_6 = 1;
public static final int PICTURES_8 = 2;
public static final int PICTURES_10 = 3;
public static final int PICTURES_12 = 4;

public static final int PICTURES_OPTION_0 = 4;
public static final int PICTURES_OPTION_1 = 6;
public static final int PICTURES_OPTION_2 = 8;
public static final int PICTURES_OPTION_3 = 10;
```

And here's an example of where I use those constant references:

```
switch (settings.getInt(SettingsActivity.PICTURES_OPTION, SettingsActivity.DEFAULT_PICTURES_OPTION)) {
        case SettingsActivity.PICTURES_4:
            totalImages = SettingsActivity.PICTURES_OPTION_0;
            break;
        case SettingsActivity.PICTURES_6:
            totalImages = SettingsActivity.PICTURES_OPTION_1;
            break;
        case SettingsActivity.PICTURES_8:
            totalImages = SettingsActivity.PICTURES_OPTION_2;
            break;
```

Essentially, I would like to know how to use a function to reduce the code but still keep the ability to use readable references. Or is my idea of using a readable reference wrong? I learned in an online programming class about using constants as readable references (such as PIXELS_PER_INCH = 72) instead of using absolute values.

Thank you for your time.

Update:
I ended up using aioobe and Lloyd Ozymandias Force's suggestions. I used `EnumMap` in a for loop. Within the for loop, though, I couldn't use `myEnumMap.values()` for some reason. I Googled it and found a different way to do it using `myEnumMap.class.getEnumConstants()`, instead.

Comment: Although the PIXELS_PER_INCH constant is fine, the rest of these constants seem to be swapping one magic number for another.

Comment: @Paul Butcher: Thanks for your reply. I created the code this way because I thought readability was one of the most important aspects of programming. I wanted readers of my code to understand what I was doing in my switch statement. But doing it this way has made the code too long and readers are complaining about it. Do you have any recommendations for maintaining readability while reducing code?

Comment: Don't worry about reducing code, think about increasing the readability.  I don't understand why this switch/case translates (e.g.) PICTURES_18 (7) into PICTURES_OPTION_7 (18).  What do all of these numbers mean, and what goal are you trying to achieve by translating between them?  Try to express that intent in the code.

Comment: Readability/understandability is definitely important.  And while the layout is good, all I (for example) can tell is that `PICTURES_6` implies `PICTURES_OPTION_1`.  That's meaningless.  Give the constants better names like `PICTURE_OPTION_RESIZE` and `SAVE_BUTTON_ICON` and readability will remarkably improve.

Comment: @Paul Butcher, @Andrzej Doyle, @aioobe, @Lloyd Ozymandias Force: My app uses an Android widget called a spinner. It's basically a drop-down menu. I call a get method from the spinner that returns a number from a 0-based list, representing the option chosen from the menu. The option chosen is just a number and is not easily readable. So, I created constants that try to explain the meaning of the chosen option. If the user chooses option 1, it is PICTURES_OPTION_0 and the meaning is PICTURES_4, because option 1 is 4 pictures.

Comment: Could you show the code that populates the spinner? What do the options look like to the user?

Comment: @Ishtar: The code that populates the spinner is not very meaningful. It's `ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.numberPictures, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);`.numberPictures is an array of strings defined in an XML file. But for the user, the options are a simple drop-down menu with the number 4 for the first option, 6 for the second, and so on. The complicated use of constants is more for readability for other programmers, not so much for the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You can put the options in a map, and do `get(option)` instead of `switch(option)`

  Initialize the map like this:

  ```
  Map<Integer, Integer> optionsMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>() {{
      put(SettingsActivity.PICTURES_4, SettingsActivity.PICTURES_OPTION_0);
      put(SettingsActivity.PICTURES_6, SettingsActivity.PICTURES_OPTION_1);
      ...
  }};
  ```

  and then replace the switch like this:

  ```
  totalImages = optionsMap.get(settings.getInt(SettingsActivity.PICTURES_OPTION,
                                     SettingsActivity.DEFAULT_PICTURES_OPTION));
  ```
- Or, (since you seem to have a simple integer to integer mapping) you could put your values in a [lookup table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table).
- Or, you can put it in a function and replace all breaks with returns:

  ```
  public int getPictureOption() {
      switch (settings.getInt(SettingsActivity.PICTURES_OPTION,
                              SettingsActivity.DEFAULT_PICTURES_OPTION)) {
              case SettingsActivity.PICTURES_4:
                  return SettingsActivity.PICTURES_OPTION_0;

              case SettingsActivity.PICTURES_6:
                  return SettingsActivity.PICTURES_OPTION_1;

              case SettingsActivity.PICTURES_8:
                  return SettingsActivity.PICTURES_OPTION_2;
      }
  }
  ```

  and then do

  ```
  totalImages = getPictureOption();
  ```

---

If you consider your constants to be self explanatory, you could get rid of all `SettingsActivity.` by adding a static import in the top of your file:

```
import static your.package.SettingsActivity.*;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The people I've showed my code to have said that my switch statements are too long. In the actual code, my switch statements are about 16 case statements long, as the PICTURES_# and PICTURES_OPTION_# code continues. I was wondering if I could maintain the readability of my code while using a function to reduce the code. Readability in terms of "what is this switch statement doing?" With the long version of the code, it's somewhat easier to understand what's happening, but it's too long.

Comment: Updated the first option in my answer.

Comment: I think I'll put my constants into an EnumMap and use your first suggestion. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Do not switch on enum values - this is a job for polymorphism or a Map / look up table as mentioned by aiobe.

To illustrate one technique for working with enums in Java, consider the following SettingsActivity enum with a polymorphic getPictureOption() method. It is declared abstract in the enum body, forcing each enum constant to implement that method. This technique is described in more detail in Effective Java 2nd Edition (Josh Bloch).

```
enum SettingsActivity {
    OPTION_1(){
        public int getPicureOption() {
            return  myValue * 6;
        }
    },
    OPTION_2(){
        public int getPictureOption() {
            return Math.pow(myValue,5);
        }
    },
    ...
    OPTION_N() {
        public int getPictureOption() {
            return myValue-6;
        }
    };

    private final int myValue;

    private SettingsActivity(int myValue) {
        this.myValue = myValue;
    }

    // enums can have abstract methods!
    public abstract int getPictureOption();
}

SettingsActivity foo = getSettingsActivityFromSomewhere();

// polymorphic getPictureOption method - we don't
// know which activity was clicked
int something = foo.getPictureOption();
```

Of course, this is just sample code to illustrate the kind of thing you can do. I'm not sure what the intent of your switch statement is or where the SettingsActivity enum comes from so I can't really offer more guidance.

In case you want to use a Map, the EnumMap class provided by the JDK provides an ultra efficient Map implementation for enums (it's implemented as a single long value for enums with fewer than 65 constants and an array of long values for > 64 constants). Either way, the look up operations are O(1) (as opposed to O(lg n) for a hash map).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually, SettingsActivity is not an enum. It's a class and the constants are static constants (such as PICTURES_#). It was the only way I knew how to access a variable from one class while in another class.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion of using EnumMap. I'll make use of that and aioobe's first suggestion.